# Pycharm jupyter notebook wsl: Jupyter package is not installed

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to use Jupyter notebook inside Pycharm. The project interpreter is a python2.7 from a virtual environment inside WSL (ubuntu 18.04).

The Jupiter package is correctly installed inside the virtual environment (I can run it by `jupyter notebook`).

My problem is that when I want to use Jupyter notebook inside Pycharm, I get the following error: `Run Error Jupyter package is not installed` (see picture).

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34927

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this problem in Python 3. Below are the steps I took to resolve the issue; I believe they should resolve the issue for you too:

1. I had Jupyter Lab installed. Pycharm only works with Jupyter Notebook. Long story short, if you have Jupyter Lab installed you need to uninstall all your packages using:

   $ pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
2. Restart your computer
3. Follow [Jupyter Notebook installation instructions](https://jupyter.org/install)
4. Make sure WSL is set up through pycharm instructions: [wsl pycharm instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html)
5. In Pycharm, open an .ipynb file. Click the dropdown that says "Managed Jupyter server" It's right above the text editor. Select "configure Jupyter server". Check configured server.
6. In your wsl terminal, type jupyter notebook. Copy and paste the text that looks like: http://localhost:8888/?token=874asdf687asd6fasd8f74ds6f4s9d8f7sddf into the cofigured server box in Pycharm.

That's it. You should be able to run the jupyter cells in pycharm now.

Comment: but i cannot access local code in this way. import failed.

Answer (score 4):

I have Pycharm 2020.3 For me the issue was I was using a virtual environment with "inherit global site packages." I had Jupyter installed in global site packages but NOT the virtual environment.

Once I installed Jupyter within the virtual environment Jupyter notebook worked. Not sure why inheriting Jupyter from global packages wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution using a designated url with token seems to work with older versions of PyCharm. A simpler solution is to upgrade to the latest PyCharm. I no longer had an issue with the auto server using PyCharm 2019.3.2 (Mac)

Comment: The OP mentioned that this is an issue with WSL, so I wouldn't expect this to be a problem on Mac. I updated to the latest PyCharm 2019.3.3 on Windows and had the same issue as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Datalore plugin enabled on 2020.2 linux, running on bare metal but displaying to a remote X server (probably doesn't matter). My solution was to disable the Datalore plugin (it's enabled for professional pycharm by default).

This way I was still able to use the "managed" auto-start version with better integration / debugging vs the "configured" option (or at least with less hassle).

Note since it's been a year, my problem is probably different than OP.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me, when the interpreter was a remote one.  I fixed this by changing the interpreter to one from a local env.
This can be done by selecting the Configure Jupyter Server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem,and i solved it

i create the new project with the global sit-packages like below

[image]

then i meet the problem

i create the new  project with **no global sit-packages** and install jupyter notebook in the virtualenv

[image]

then the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by changing the project interpreter to the one I wanted.  If it's just an interpreter on a run config that doesn't provide enough info to PyCharm.  I'm reluctant to create

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).