# "Jupyter package is not installed" error message in Pycharm (using Windows). How do I fix this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I downloaded Pycharm 2019.3 and I am using it with the most recent Anaconda distribution for Python 3.

The Jupyter package is installed - I can see it in the Project Interpreter's list of packages and I can run the notebook from the Windows command line.

When I try to run a cell (or all cells) within Pycharm, a pop up error message says "Jupyter package is not installed".

My problem is similar to this one but I am running directly on Windows. [Pycharm jupyter notebook wsl: Jupyter package is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303216/pycharm-jupyter-notebook-wsl-jupyter-package-is-not-installed)

How can I make Pycharm recognise the Jupyter package?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, for me it was an issue with mismatched interpreters.
The python interpreter on my toolbar (which is the same as settings -> project -> project interpreter) didn't match the one selected for the jupyter server (settings -> build,execution,deployment -> jupyter -> jupyter servers.